# Wix WebApplicationExtension prevents unintalling WebApplication

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

i'm installing a WebApplication in IIS. Installation is running OK, but when i try to uninstall my product, the WebApplication is left behind in IIS. All files are removed, but the WebApp still shows up in IIS manager console.
This is my component code:

```
<!-- WebServices Virtual Directory -->
<Component Id="IWSVirtualDirectory" Guid="{XXXX...}" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Win64="no">
    <!-- Virtual directory -->
      <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="IWSWebVirtualDirectory" Alias="[IWS_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME]" Directory="MyWebServices" WebSite="IWSTargetWebSite">
         <!-- Web Application -->
         <iis:WebApplication Id="IWSWebApplication" Name="MyWebServices-$(var.MAJOR).$(var.MINOR).3" WebAppPool="IWSWebAppPool">
            <!-- ISAPI filter -->
            <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="dll" CheckPath="yes" Script="yes" Executable="[#FTIRWWSIsapi_dll]" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
            <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension="srf" CheckPath="yes" Script="yes" Executable="[#FTIRWWSIsapi_dll]" Verbs="GET,HEAD" />
         </iis:WebApplication>
        <!-- Properties -->
        <iis:WebDirProperties Id="IWSWebDirProperties" Read="yes" LogVisits="yes" Index="yes" Script="yes" Execute="no" DefaultDocuments="FTIRWWS.htm" BasicAuthentication="no" PassportAuthentication="no" DigestAuthentication="no" IIsControlledPassword="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
      </iis:WebVirtualDir>                               
    </Component>
```

Edit:
Oddly, the WebApplication is actually removed if i delete the two `<iis:WebApplicationExtension />` those are just mapping handlers to file extensions to be served by the application. Why would the handler mappings prevent the WebApplication from being uninstalled?? Are there any logs to check what's going on apart from Windows Installer logs?

Answer (score 1):

The property you use for defining the virtual directory alias (application name) is not set properly on uninstall. When you run the installation, you probably set the `IWS_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME` somehow (asking the user, some logic, etc.) But on uninstall this property doesn't get set, and WiX can't find the virtual directory to remove on uninstall.

This is a common mistake people tend to make. You have to store the value of `IWS_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME` somehow. The best known approach [is described by Rob Mensching and is called "Remember the property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern). Follow the suggestion in that article, and you'll be able to store the properties in between install and uninstall.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Ashamed of myself, i forgot to include some important information in the question. It was mentioned in the Title but not in the question's body. Also, about the 'IWS_VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY_NAME', it always has the same value '"MyService"'. So the Alias is always set.